# c++ if statement with compound value

Tags: c++

i'm trying to find a solution that allows me to take this snip:

```
cout << antalVaerelser << ("-v\x91r, ") 
<< (altan == true ? ("med altan, ") : ("uden altan, "));

if (etage == 0) {
cout << ("stuen ");
}
else {
cout << etage << (" etage ");
}

cout << areal << (" m2") << endl;
```

and transform it at bit to have a line that is more like this:

```
cout << antalVaerelser << ("-v\x91r, ")
<< (altan == true ? ("med altan, ") : ("uden altan, "))
<< (etage==0?("stuen ") : etage + (" etage "))
<< areal << (" m2")
<< endl;
```

however this does not work as some of the output seems to be "eaten" - it would be displayed as "4-vær, med altan, age, 101m2" where "age" should have been the value of etage (value=1-4) followed by the string " etage, "

This would also work, but it seems really excessive:

```
(etage == 0 ? ("stuen ") : etage == 1 ? ("1 etage ") : etage == 2 ? ("2 etage ") : etage == 3 ? ("3 etage ") : ("4 etage "))
```

so the question is thus: how (if at all possible) would i something like this work?:

```
(etage==0?("stuen ") : etage + (" etage "))
```

thank you in advance :)

Comment: `etage` is an `int`, yes?  Why are you trying to add it to a string?

Comment: Use `if` statements - makes the code easier to read.

Comment: It's hard to tell without [mcve], but, I suspect that `etage` is an `int`, and adding `int` and a `const char*` results in a _pointer arithmetic_ being performed, and not `string` concatenation, as you, probably, expected.

Comment: Stay with `if` statements. Conditional operator doesn't gain you anything except making the code harder to read and make **maintenance much harder**.

Comment: @ScottHunter Correct, `etage` is an `int`. I want this because the output display should show the value of `etage` followed by the string `" etage, "`

Comment: well i do know that `etage + (" etage ")` wont work of cause, what i'm looking for is something that will do as i mentioned in my last comment.

it should be noted that i'm a utter and complete newbie in c++ ... heck in coding in general. so much of what should be second nature, and the most obvious, has not yet taken hold.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two problems

- ternary operator must return values of same type
- adding integer and string literal doesn't work as you are expecting

to do it in C++11

```
cout << antalVaerelser << ("-v\x91r, ")
    << (altan == true ? "med altan, " : "uden altan, ")
    << (etage==0 ? std::string("stuen ") : std::to_string(etage) + " etage ")
    << areal << (" m2")
    << endl;
```

in C++14 a bit nicer:

```
cout << antalVaerelser << ("-v\x91r, ")
    << (altan == true ? "med altan, " : "uden altan, ")
    << (etage==0 ? "stuen "s : std::to_string(etage) + " etage "s)
    << areal << (" m2"s)
    << endl;
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be _doesn't work as you are expecting_ ?

Comment: isn't it called ternary, not trinary?

Comment: using C++ 15


seemed promising, but when using `std::to_string(etage) + " etage "` i get a warning `namespase std has no member "to_string"`

`"stuen "` gets me an `user-defined literal operator not found`

Comment: @ToKeLu Read [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) first. [Here is proof that it works](https://wandbox.org/permlink/rtt021F41X6zg7v3). Here is [C++14 version](https://wandbox.org/permlink/UJNCfXvMnn9d4Ps5).

Comment: I did read the documentation, and i did not contest that it should work.
but as stated before - i am a newbie :D - problem were that i overlooked the need for `#include <string>`
works as advertised, Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You can't concatenate the int and the string like that.

Try wrapping an int in `std::to_string(myInt)` then adding a string to that, that forces it to be string + string concatenation like you want.

Reference:
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert the number to string like this:

```
cout << (etage == 0 ? "stuen " : std::to_string(etage) + " etage");
```

**std::to_string()** helps you to convert your `int' to`string`.

You can also do it like this if it is just a concatenation matter:

```
etage == 0 ? cout << "stuen " : cout << etage <<" etage";
```